# how to stop creating object Instance when its not need

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The class do have

```
 -(void) trackByPage : (NSString*) pageName {

        TrackPage *track_p;
            = [[TrackPage alloc] init];
            track_p.page1 = @"welcome";
            track_p.page2= self.String1;
            [track_p release];
    }
```

I am accessing from controller class this method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    TrackPageMeasurement *trackPage_Measurement = [[TrackPageMeasurement alloc]init];
    [trackPage_Measurement trackByPage:@"Msg"];
    [trackPage_Measurement release];
}

- (void)selectedDataValue {


    TrackPageMeasurement *trackPage_Measurement = [[TrackPageMeasurement alloc]init];
    [trackPage_Measurement trackByPage:@"DataValue"];
    [trackPage_Measurement release];
}
```

I am accessing that through another class. trackByPage. by passing string ..

Each time i am accessing each time object instance is created how to stop those thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
TrackPage *track_p;

if(track_p==nil)
{
      track_p= [[TrackPage alloc] init];
      track_p.page1 = @"welcome";
      track_p.page2= self.String1;

}

[track_p release];
```

Comment: That create an overrelease, and if you put the release inside the conditional, there's no point in the conditional.

Comment: Beyond an overrelease, it creates a dangling pointer that'll cause hell later.

Answer (score 2):

`selectedDataValue` shouldn't be calling `[super viewDidLoad];`  The code doesn't exactly inspire me with confidence; it looks to me more like that you want to retrieve some tracking object rather than creating a new one each time.  Do you know what a singleton is?

Using a singleton would look more like:

```
TrackPage *track_p = [TrackPage instance];
track_p.page1 = @"welcome";
track_p.page2 = self.String1;
```

Comment: yeap Paul Lynch i agree that. its need to there I copy paste make some error thanks for point it.

Comment: yeap i am tracking the OminatureService for that.

Comment: I say that because it is not clear what you are trying to do; see my answer.

Comment: i am creating an singleton and access the method where i am tracking the method with that method.

Comment: No: or at least, in the code above you aren't using singletons.  You are creating instances of TrackPage and TrackPageMeasurement, setting some values, then immediately disposing of them.